# getting the same critical values in johansen test

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistical-test

So I am trying to make an algorithm that test for cointegration:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import os
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as ts
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen

df = pd.DataFrame()
data = []
csv_file = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser("/Users/benitocano/Downloads/copyOfSandP500.csv"), delimiter = ',')
tickers = pd.read_csv("/Users/benitocano/Downloads/copyOfSandP500.csv", delimiter=',', names = ['Symbol', 'Name', 'Sector'])
#Get the asset data
def get_data():
    start = dt.datetime(2020, 5, 30)
    end = dt.datetime.now()
    for ticker in tickers['Symbol'][:3]:
        try:
            df1 = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df1.drop(['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume'], axis=1, inplace=True)     
            data.append(df1)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        for stock in data:     
            series = pd.Series(stock['Adj Close'])
            df[ticker] = series
        df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

#test if each asset is Nonstationary or not>
def ADF_Test():
    for ticker, prices in df.iteritems():
        adf_statistic = ts.adfuller(prices, 1)
        for key, value in adf_statistic[4].items():
            value = value
        test_stat = value < adf_statistic[0]
        pvalue_stat = adf_statistic[1] > .05
        if pvalue_stat==False and test_stat==False:
            df.drop(ticker, axis=1, inplace=True)
            

def get_spread():
    pass
    data1 = []
    a = 0
    b = a
    
    for y in range (a, len(df.columns)):
        b = a+1

        for e in range (b, len(df.columns)):
            if e == y:
                pass
            else:    
                ticker_1 = df.columns[e]
                ticker_2 = df.columns[y]
                ticker_dict = {
                ticker_1 : df[ticker_1],
                ticker_2 : df[ticker_2]
                }
                ticker_frame = pd.DataFrame(ticker_dict)
                result = coint_johansen(ticker_frame, 0, 1)
                trace_statistic = result.lr1[0]
                critical_value = result.cvt
                print("trace statistic: {}".format(trace_statistic))
                print("Critcal values: {}".format(critical_value))


        b = b+1


get_data()
ADF_Test()
get_spread()
```

What the algorithm is doing, is gathering data from a csv file, then putting all into one dataframe. It is then deciding which companies are stationary and which are not. Finally it is running a for loop where it is creating all of the possible pairs and putting them into seperate dataframes. Then finally running the Johansen test on those dataframes. The issue is that when I print out the code, all of the critical values are the same. The output is:

```
trace statistic: 9.736276687870111
Critcal values: [[13.4294 15.4943 19.9349]
 [ 2.7055  3.8415  6.6349]]
trace statistic: 14.374497415885136
Critcal values: [[13.4294 15.4943 19.9349]
 [ 2.7055  3.8415  6.6349]]
trace statistic: 8.388038242212934
Critcal values: [[13.4294 15.4943 19.9349]
 [ 2.7055  3.8415  6.6349]]
trace statistic: 8.388038242212934
Critcal values: [[13.4294 15.4943 19.9349]
 [ 2.7055  3.8415  6.6349]]
```

Why are all the values coming out the same given this would be almost statisticaly immpossible? Also, for simplicty I only indexed out the first 3 companies to run this code, but it does not matter the size I still am getting the same problem. thanks!

The csv file can be found at: https://datahub.io/core/s-and-p-500-companies

Comment: If the critical value is based upon the same probability, then the critical values could absolutely be the same for every company. See https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/basic-statistics/inference/supporting-topics/basics/what-is-a-critical-value/

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with those results? Also what probability is it calculating that makes it the same values?

Comment: Percentiles of 90, 95, and 99. This is where it's calculated: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/32011b6b5e89e1e9d8061cd210406790d4ee7430/statsmodels/tsa/coint_tables.py#L119

Comment: though how is it possible that all the pairs in the S&P have the same critical values?